# Como resolver erro keyError: 0 ao rodar o código no Heroku, porém no pycharm o script está rodando certinho?

Tags: python

Bom dia, estou tendo um problema ao rodar o código phyton de um script no Heroku.
No PyCharm o código está sendo executado sem nenhum problema, não da nenhum erro e fica rodando por dias, só para quando eu desligo o PC. Dessa forma, optei por jogar o código para rodar nos servidores da Heroku, já que é um código simples e eu não pago nada pra ele ser executado, evitando assim ficar com o pc ligado só para executar o script.

O problema é que só na heroku que está dando o erro, e eu não sei o que pode ser.

Log de erro da Heroku:

```
2022-10-10T14:25:00.276682+00:00 heroku[worker.1]: Starting process with command `python main.py`
2022-10-10T14:25:00.894856+00:00 heroku[worker.1]: State changed from starting to up
2022-10-10T14:25:02.001125+00:00 heroku[worker.1]: Process exited with status 1
2022-10-10T14:25:01.807812+00:00 app[worker.1]: Traceback (most recent call last):
2022-10-10T14:25:01.807840+00:00 app[worker.1]:   File "/app/main.py", line 34, in <module>
2022-10-10T14:25:01.807979+00:00 app[worker.1]:     val = float(r[x]["crash_point"])
2022-10-10T14:25:01.808014+00:00 app[worker.1]: KeyError: 0
2022-10-10T14:25:02.085083+00:00 heroku[worker.1]: State changed from up to crashed
```

Script Phyton:

```
from typing import List
import requests, time, threading
import json

token = ''
chat_id = ''

while True:

    url = 'https://blaze.com/api/crash_games/recent'

    try:
        response = requests.get(url)
        r = response.json()
    except:
        print("Não deu")

    ray = []
    crash_list = []


    for x in range(len(r)):
        val = float(r[x]["crash_point"])
        if val < 2:
            val = "V"
        else:
            val = "P"

        ray.append(val)
```

OBSERVAÇÃO: Eu imagino que o erro esteja acontecendo pois não está encontrando o valor de "crash_point" retornado da api da Blaze, mas no PyCharm ele encontra o resultado normalmente.

Não sei como solucionar, se alguém puder me dar uma luz, agradeço!

Comment: "*Eu imagino que o erro esteja acontecendo pois não está encontrando o valor de "crash_point"*", **errado**! O erro diz que o erro é por não achar o índice 0: `KeyError: 0`. O ideal seria validar o valor de `r` antes de tentar acessá-lo, visto que seu código executará mesmo quando uma exceção ocorre.

Comment: Ou seja, garanta que a requisição foi realizada com sucesso antes de tratar o corpo da resposta.

Comment: @Woss Boa tarde, obrigado pela resposta!

Você conseguiria me ajudar a resolver isso? sou um recém ingressado estudando de desenvolvimento de sistemas e me perco muito na sintaxe do phyton ainda, eu compreendo a lógica da programação, o argumento de except foi justamente para resolver um problema de a lista que recebo da api em alguns momento não retornava em formato json, e meu script parava, ai pensei nessa solução apenas para o código continuar rodando, talvez seja ai o problema. Já que no Pycharm não é problema, é apenas no Heroku que o script não executa. De qualquer forma, agradeço!